# Measure and Track Value of Website(s) Improvements

Tags: tracking, impressions, measure, upgrade

is there any way to track and measure a website's value over time? Here is what I mean (btw, very green at this, so no judgement, but constructive criticism is appreciated)

We have several websites that we want to revamp.  They're getting old, outdated in many sense of the word (looks, image, content, technology).

Some of the improvements, will affect SEO positively, so that makes it easier to see and I guess if the bounce rate goes down, that could be an indicator...

But is there tricks and such to kind of take an overall snapshot of the state and do this every so often and keep track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should set goals for each website. These vary widely - for an ecommerce site, obviously a purchase is one goal; for a content site, perhaps time on page is a better indicator of whether visitors are really taking the time to read content, or email signup could be a big conversion. Only you know what your goal is with each site you own.

It's free and relatively easy to set up each goal in Google Analytics. This will give you (from the time you set up the goal, forward) the best, easiest way to figure out a baseline and compare month to month, year to year.

It often also makes sense to set up "events" which aren't necessarily goals, but which indicate a visitor has done something important on your site, such as watched a YouTube video, clicked a button with a particular CSS class that indicates it was a call to action you want to track, that type of thing. You can also compare how many events each different visitor segment is completing to tell whether, for example, visitors from a certain search engine are not doing many desired actions and you may want to focus more on visitors from other sites.

Comment: This is definitely pointing me in the right direction. Thanks